# separating json diff results contained inside of an InputStream into a map in Java

Tags: java, json, jackson, inputstream

I'm receiving a Supplier into a method that will create an object based on each change that was made according to a JsonDiff.  The Supplier is set up like so:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

// jsons to compare
String json1= "{}";
String json2= "{\"name\":\"Sean\", \"state\":\"Colorado\"}";

// convert jsons to JsonNode
JsonNode json1Node = mapper.readTree(json1);
JsonNode json2Node = mapper.readTree(json2);

// create Supplier<InputStream>
Supplier<InputStream> diffs = () ->
    new ByteArrayInputStream(JsonDiff.asJson(json1Node, json2Node).toString().getBytes());
```

The resulting diff (between converting it into an InputStream) would look something like this:

```
[{"op":"add", "path": "/name", "value": "Sean"}, {"op":"add", "path": "/State", "value": "Colorado"}]
```

When I receive this supplier, I want to be able to separate each patch into an object.  The object would simply store information, set up like:

```
private enum Op { 
 ADD, REPLACE, REMOVE
}

private Op op;
private String path;
private String value;

public Patch(Op op, String path, String value {
    this.op = op;
    this.path = path;
    this.value = value;
}

// getter methods
```

From this particular example, I should be able to create 2 objects, 1 for the name, and 1 for the state.

My attempt was like so:

```
private List<Patch> patches;
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

try {
    // convert JSON string to Map
    map = mapper.readValue(diffs.get().toString(), new TypeReference<HashMap<String, String>>() {});

    // create patches
    for (String value : map.values()) {
        HashMap<String, String> result = mapper.readValue(value, HashMap.class);
        patches.add(new Patch(Patch.Op.valueOf(result.get("op").toUpperCase()), result.get("path"), result.get("value")));
    }
}catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

It throws the following exception on the "readValue" line:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'java': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@1abf3bf; line: 1, column: 5]
```

It seems (at least this is my interpretation) that the diff.get().toString() call isn't returning anything remotely close to Json.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Does the JsonDiff class have a toString method?  What do you get when you print diffs.get().toString() to the console?

Comment: it returns:
java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@f4d528

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the result of the jsondiff is an array, you might have an issue getting it parsed into a map instead of a list.
Further more you shouldn't have to call the toString() method of the Supplier output.

Here is a working example using a recent version of jackson:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.1-1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.fge</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-patch</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
        </dependency>


public class Json {
    static class Patch {
        enum Op {
            ADD, REMOVE, REPLACE;
        };

        private final Op op;
        private final String path;
        private final String value;

        @JsonCreator
        public Patch(//
                @JsonProperty("op") String op, //
                @JsonProperty("path") String path, //
                @JsonProperty("value") String value) {
            this.op = Op.valueOf(op.toUpperCase());
            this.path = path;
            this.value = value;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Patch [op=" + op + ", path=" + path + ", value=" + value + "]";
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        // jsons to compare
        String json1 = "{}";
        String json2 = "{\"name\":\"Sean\", \"state\":\"Colorado\"}";

        // convert jsons to JsonNode
        JsonNode json1Node = mapper.readTree(json1);
        JsonNode json2Node = mapper.readTree(json2);

        // create Supplier<InputStream>
        final String strDiff = JsonDiff.asJson(json1Node, json2Node).toString();
        Supplier<InputStream> diffs = () -> new ByteArrayInputStream(strDiff.getBytes());

        MappingIterator<Patch> iterator = new ObjectMapper()//
                .readerFor(Patch.class) //
                .readValues(diffs.get());

        List<Patch> patches = new ArrayList<>();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            patches.add(iterator.next());
        }
        System.out.println(patches);
    }
}
```

output is:

```
[Patch [op=ADD, path=/name, value=Sean], Patch [op=ADD, path=/state, value=Colorado]]
```